# Table styling with R Markdown Beamer Presentations (long tables, width issue and linebreaks)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pander

I tried many things before and I know that it is a pain to deal with tables already, but I am still asking if there is an easy way to handle tables in Beamer presentations created by RMarkdown.

Here is my MWE containing three different table creation methods `xtable`, `kable` and `pander`.

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r,echo=FALSE}
set.seed(34123)
test_df<-data.frame(name_column=rep(c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Only lorem"),15),
            column_1=as.character(round(runif(30,10^6,2*10^6),4)),
            column_2=as.character(round(runif(30,10^6,2*10^6),4)),
            column_3=as.character(round(runif(30,10^6,2*10^6),4)))
```

## MWE xtable

```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
print(xtable(test_df),include.rownames=FALSE,comment=FALSE)
```

## MWE pander

```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
pander(test_df,split.cells=c("25%","25%","25%","25%"))
```

## MWE kable

```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
kable(test_df)
```
````

What I want

- Page breaks for long tables
- Width fitting
- Line breaks for given fixed column widths (better if I can specify the percentages) and alignments.
- No extra row spaces

I could get those separately. For instance, I can use `adjustbox` with xtable but if it is a longtable environment adjustbox is no longer applicable. I can specify alignments with parameters such as `p{3cm}` but I lose alignment. If I am to specify special codes for that, then it throws an error.

Long story short, I want wide and long tables to behave nicely in Beamer presentations. I am covering a wide basis here because of my data frames can spit both. Partial answers are also welcome.

Comment: Not sure if you can easily do the auto-split for long tables, as in Rmd + beamer, you will have to create the new slides between the tables. But depending on how many tables you have, you could do by hand eg `pander(test_df[1:10, ], split.cells=c("25%","25%","25%","25%"))`, then  the second batch etc -- or if you have tables, you could use `brew` preprocess the Rmd or go with `pander::Pandoc.brew` which supports looping.

Comment: Well, to be honest, `pander` has a weird styling with lots of linebreaks end up messing the whole table. I failed to make a reliable solution out of pander yet. @daroczig

Comment: @berkobay there's no `pander` style -- the package supports all 4 style defined in [pandoc's markdown](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables). If you do not like the default `multiline` (which is the most feature-rich markdown table format), you can use any of the other 3 styles by the `style` argument or set it [globally](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) via `panderOptions`.

Comment: @daroczig Sorry, let me rephrase that. I used `pander` or `pandoc.table` commands with varying styles (multiline, grid, simple if I remember correctly) and most of the time there was something problematic with . I am working on something lame and kinda manual but hopefully would do task. R code will write the table on a tabularx in a .tex file and I plan to take that table via input.